# Extreme Kerr render engine issue

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, computational-physics, event-horizon, simulations

So, me and a friend have been working on a Kerr render engine. It uses the Kerr metric of general relativity to draw the image of a black hole. Our current results look like this;

[image]

The accounted for effects are;

- Light travel delay
- Gravitational Lensing. . . obviously
- Gravitational Red/Blueshift
- Red/Blueshift from the disks rotation
- Accurate Temperature -> Color model
- Doppler Beaming

In this particular render, the Disk temperature is set to a uniform 1600 Kelvin. We have however several temperature models. This is how a more accurate one would look like using an accretion rate;

[image]

This is all fine and good. However one nitpick remains. The rate of rotation, $a$. Atm, anything above $a = +-0.9$ creates artifacts because the step size of the integrator cant get small enough. Its capped at 0.001 meters/step. Our goal is to draw the shadow at a spin of up to $a = +-0.99$. Which, atm works less well;

[image]

Note, this is at $a = 0.99$

For reference, this render took 11000000 integration steps on the left edge to finish. Where as all the other ones above could be done with 960000. There are several issues with this result

1. Anywhere the Horizon has a color, the integration finished. Meaning a ray, which went straight for the EH, somehow hit the Celestial sphere. Those Artifacts represent rays escaped to infinity.
2. Anywhere the Horizon has pure red, the integration did not finish, after 11 million steps with a step size as small as 0.0000075 m/step.

And we are at a bit of a dead end here. We know it is possible to render extreme Kerr, such as can be seen here; [image]

But lowering the step size even more across the board just becomes impractical. Since this is a test build, the step size switches to 0.0000075 if the $r < 2$ (note we work with natural units $G=M=c=1$. So the event Horizon is like 1.4 units across or something. This way, at least in theory, we get the highest range of floating point precision on top of our 64 Bit precision. There should be enough numbers to rule out numerical issues at least for now.

As such, our question is if there is a better way of doing this ? Is there a better way of solving the equations of motion (we use a 4th order integration scheme). Or is there a smart way to chose a step size ? Do any of you have experience with rendering these extreme Kerr scenarios ?

The program build able to render the images above uses basically 3 states for the step size, aside from special axis conditions to deal with the Y-Axis singularity. The basic logic is

$r > 10 \rightarrow stepSize = 20 $

$r < 10 \, \text{AND} \, r >4 \rightarrow stepSize = 2 $

$ r < 4 \rightarrow stepSize = e^{-4u}$

(Note "u" is the 4 velocity vector, so its really big close to the EH)

We could really use any ideas on how to make this work in a better way than just lower the step size and increasing the integration limiter. That's obviously an option, but tbf frank those high res renders at $a = 0.9$ already take about an hour, and if the low resolution tests are anything to go by this current faulty approach would land somewhere around 10 hours / frame.

So yeah, i hope i explained the issue. Thanks for any and help, and thank you for taking the time to read this ! And just to be clear, i am not asking for anyone to wip out code or anything, just tips and solution ways.

Comment: In my simulator [here](http://org.yukterez.net/relativistic.raytracer/falling.into.a.kerr.newman.black.hole.html) the integration ends when the step size is <0.0001 and works fine with 16 bit single precision (it can switch to arbitraty precision though), but the steps themselves are not limited since the photons grazing the edge do multiple rounds. If you use Boyer Lindquist coordinates and stay outside the horizon you also could stop the integration if the ray gets close outside the horizon and return a black pixel (I do that below r<1.0001r₊), otherwise you might get noise.

Comment: @Yukterez 0.0001 ?! What the hell, how long does that take to render ? Atm we use 3 break conditions, either the ray hits the Horizon, escapes or numerically explodes (Distance between the current and previews ray position > some threshold). And even that dosnt really work xD

Comment: That's not a fixed stepsize, the Mathematica integrator I use has variable stepsize, 0.0001 is just the minimum I allow. I don't use graphics card acceleration though, so there will be faster codes than mine. I don't know what integrator you use, so I can't really tell you how to work around its weaknesses.

Comment: @Yukterez tbf i also just use the CPU xD Probably one of the main weaknesses is the fact the integration is stopped when r < 1.25r+. Which, might be a bit optimistic. But the render times do explode without this padding. easily in the 10-15min / frame range

Comment: For a Full HD image it can take an hour to render with my code, so I test in low resolution before I render in high resolution. If you want accuracy and speed you will need Cuda or something like that, in my code the priorities were not speed, but that the code should be relatively easy to read for humans and easy to update, without graphics card acceleration I doubt that will work faster than what you call exploding render times.

Comment: @Yukterez i see. So, i am inching towards r < 1.01r+ at your smallest step rate. So far, at least the artifacts dont get much worse. And the render time somehow decrease xD But the fact yours works with 0.0001 gives me hope i am making some error which needlessly extends the render time

Comment: @Yukterez also we use a 4th order Runge-Kutta scheme if that matters